# C++ unordered_map, unordered_set - как оптимально организовать поиск

Tags: c++, stl, структуры-данных

Допустим, у нас есть класс, содержащий имя пользователя. Я хочу сделать организовать быстрый поиск по нему. Если использовать для этого unordered_map - расходуется лишняя память на хранении имени внутри структуры и в самом объекте. Если использовать unordered_set - для поиска поиска нужно создавать целый объект пользователя, так как функция сравнения принимает две константные ссылки на объекты моего класса. Написать отдельный хешер для строки и сравнить со строкой просто нельзя. Это вопрос о жадности, возникает у меня уже не раз. Можно-ли на STL сделать это оптимально - не хранить два раза имя, и не создавать объект для поиска? Если нет - в какой библиотеке реализация хеш-таблицы позволяет делать такие вещи?

Comment: Вам нужен гетерогенный поиск, а почему его нет в стандартных unordered контейнерах см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373228/why-is-there-no-stdis-transparent-equivalent-for-unordered-containers

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за ключевое слово - то что я искал. Понял что делать такое нужно на Boost.MultiIndex, хотя очень странно - для оптимальной реализации таких простых вещей уже приходится использовать библиотеки.

Comment: Ну или можно использовать обычный (не unordered) set